# A file too large makes it impossible push

Tags: git, github, repository

I can not push because of a file that exceeds the maximum size. I have seen that there are similar discussions, but following the various solutions I have failed to solve.
Here the error with the command git push:

```
Counting objects: 249, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (127/127), done.
Writing objects: 100% (130/130), 2.15 MiB | 48.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 130 (delta 93), reused 1 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (93/93), completed with 49 local 
objects.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git 
Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 8be5f11b65960921d4f91b11ce867549
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File release/RandomSamples.txt is 112.68 MB; this 
exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To HERE ADDRESS REPOSITORY
! [remote rejected] MYBRANCH -> MYBRANCH (pre-receive hook declined)
```

What can I do?

Comment: Try [Git Large File Storage](https://github.com/blog/1986-announcing-git-large-file-storage-lfs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved like this:
I want do push but I can't because there is a file too large. Then I want do:

```
git add -A .
git commit -m "Remove deleted files"
git push
```

for delete this too large file. But I can't, ever for the presence of that too large file. With

```
git status
```

I saw that I was 3 commit ahead my remote repository. Thus I did:

```
git reset HEAD^
git reset HEAD^
git reset HEAD^
```

(HEAD^ because I'm on Unix system else HEAD-1 may be)
and later again

```
git add -A .
git commit -m "Remove deleted files"
git push
```

that this time works, and with wich I was able to delete this damned file from remote.

That all

Answer (score 0):

As has been suggested by [Choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba) in the responses to your question, and has been suggested by the console output itself you will need to use [Git LFS for this](https://git-lfs.github.com/).

It is always worth considering whether you really need to be storing an object in source control if it is so large, there may be better solutions. If it's a binary dependency that won't be changing there are better solutions such as artifact repositories, if it's a build artifact of your project should you really be distributing it in source control?

Comment: I deleted the large file from locale. But the file still appear on remote.But I haven't the necessity of use it. Thus I don't mine of Git Large File Storage

Comment: Sorry, your comment is unclear. ".But I haven't the necessity of use it."   You don't need the file? You don't 'mine' Git LFS?

Comment: Yes, I don't care of Git Large File Storage and I don't need of it was right locutions. Sorry.